# Red5 Error executing call: Service: null Method: closeStream Num Params: 0

Tags: java, red5

I'm getting quite a few of the the following errors on Red5 1.0.5 using a Windows 2008 R2 server.

I tried putting a closeStream function in the server app but it hasn't seemed to help.

```
2015-07-07 21:08:10,458 [RTMPConnectionExecutor#DCFPLXM1YIXYJ-1] ERROR o.r.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Error executing call: Service: null Method: closeStream Num Params: 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.red5.server.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:193) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.invokeCall(RTMPHandler.java:210) [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:269) [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:105) [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:57) [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:11) [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1453) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.red5.server.stream.PlaylistSubscriberStream.close(PlaylistSubscriberStream.java:289) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.stream.StreamService.closeStream(StreamService.java:156) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.stream.StreamService.closeStream(StreamService.java:112) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: You may have found a bug, I'll take a look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

This is / was a bug in the server-common library; it is now fixed with this commit: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/commit/c090111aada85abbc922c4931d25f5083b81c97c

Comment: Cool!... Appreciate the quick fix.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the latest .jar?

Comment: You can always find the latest jars over at Apache's build server; for this particular part of Red5, find it here:  https://builds.apache.org/view/All/job/Red5-server-common/

Answer (score 0):

It looked like the only jar there that was changed was the red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar but when we use that one, it throws the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolEncoder.encodePacket(RTMPProtocolEncoder.java:136) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmpt.RTMPTServlet.handleBadRequest(RTMPTServlet.java:144) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmpt.RTMPTServlet.service(RTMPTServlet.java:452) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core.jar:7.0.57]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```